# How to change a date by altering a variable using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a date choosing feature, where the user clicks a button and the date goes to yesterday's date or tomorrow's. I'm using moment.js (http://momentjs.com/). I'm thinking that if I create a variable and store it within the .add method that I'll then be able to modify the variable with a jQuery click. I'm just not sure how to do this. Here's what I have so far:

```
var n = 0;

var displayDate = moment().add(n, 'days').format('MMMM Do');

$(".left-arrow").click(function(){
    n++;
    return displayDate;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/oL28ffya/

html

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<div class="left-arrow">Left (-)</div>
<div class="right-arrow">Right (+)</div>
```

js

```
var displayDate = moment()
$('#foo').text(displayDate.format('MMMM Do'))

$(".left-arrow").click(function(){
    $('#foo').text(displayDate.add(-1, 'days').format('MMMM Do'));
});

$(".right-arrow").click(function(){
    $('#foo').text(displayDate.add(1, 'days').format('MMMM Do'));
});
```

You don't need a variable to store change, when user clicks right or left, we update new date by adding/subtracting 1 and display it

Comment: Where's the explanation? Code only answers are not very helpful

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my answer, the main point is we need find new ``n`` then calculate new date.

Comment: `displayDate` should be correctly formatted also in declaration

Comment: note that returning anything but `false` in a click handler does absolutely nothing

Comment: @madox2 why? it is a stored object that can then be modified at any time and formatted as it is needed

Comment: @charlietfl I've update my code in my answer https://jsfiddle.net/oL28ffya/

Comment: @charlietfl you are right but it depends how author wants/needs to represent the state.

Comment: OMG! @LeNhatAnh thank you sooo much. This is exactly what I needed. I spent like two days trying to figure this out. You're the man/woman/whatever-you-want-be

Comment: I have a follow up question: I now want the #foo to inform a condition for the page's content. _______ if ($('#foo').text() == "April 8th"){
    $('#box').text("reading 1");
    $('#box2').text("reading 2");
    $('#box3').text("reading 3");  
};) _____

So if someone clicks the left arrow, #foo will update to April 7th and allow this to run: ______

 if ($('#foo').text() == "April 7th"){
    $('#box').text("reading 1");
    $('#box2').text("reading 2");
    $('#box3').text("reading 3");  
};) _____

It currently doesn't work, but would you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit incomplete. To get a date changer, the following would work for you:

```js
$('#foo').html(moment().format('MMMM Do'))
$(".datechange").on('click', function(){
    var d = moment($('#foo').text(), 'MMMM Do'); // parse the current date
    $('#foo').html(d.add($(this).data("datechange"), 'days').format('MMMM Do')); // update the content with the new date
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
<button class="datechange" data-datechange="-10">-10
</button>
<button class="datechange" data-datechange="-1">-1
</button>
<button class="datechange" data-datechange="1">+1
</button>
<button class="datechange" data-datechange="10">+10
</button>
```